# how to use setbounds to position JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, jtextfield

Trying to Setbound 5 Textfield in a row, but whatever I write in Setbound nothing changes.
I'm trying to put all 5 Textfields inside panel so I can position it better, tried without it but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong, I'm still learning.
Trying to Setbound 5 Textfield in a row, but whatever I write in Setbound nothing changes.
I'm trying to put all 5 Textfields inside panel so I can position it better, tried without it but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong, I'm still learning.
package com.company;

```
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
           UserInterface ui = new UserInterface();
           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(ui);
    
    
        }
    }
```

/

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class UserInterface extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;


    public void run(){

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Pogodi rijec");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800,800);


        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        Components(frame.getContentPane()); // saljem frame


        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(168,173,180));
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,100,100));
    }
    public void Components(Container container){



        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        panel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JTextField one = new JTextField();
        JTextField two = new JTextField();
        JTextField three = new JTextField();
        JTextField four = new JTextField();
        JTextField five = new JTextField();

        one.setBounds(100,100,300,300);
        two.setBounds(200,100,300,300);
        three.setBounds(200,100,300,300);
        four.setBounds(200,100,300,300);
        five.setBounds(200,100,300,300);


        panel.add(one);
        panel.add(two);
        panel.add(three);
        panel.add(four);
        panel.add(five);


        container.add(panel);


    }
    public JFrame getFrame() {

        return frame;

    }
}
```

Comment: *Trying to Setbound 5 Textfield in a row,* - Don't!!! Swing was designed to be used with Layout Managers. The FlowLayout will already display the text fields in a single row. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples and better structured code. A couple is issues with your code: 1) use `new JTextField(10)` to allow the text field to size itself to display about 10 characters. 2) The frame should be made visible AFTER the components have been added to the frame.